# Handle stored procedure output

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have this procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [xyz].[stored_proc]
    @input1 as int, 
    @input2 as nvarchar(255)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE ...
    SET input1=@input1
    WHERE input2=@input2 AND
    input3 NOT IN (123)
END
```

I want to catch update clause output and return it as procedure output parameter, so I can handle it in my .net code. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Will the UPDATE always affect exactly one row only? And what do you mean by OUTPUT? the whole row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any `OUTPUT` clause just yet - but if you did have it, what you need to do is simply run this stored procedure as if it returned a result set (from a `SELECT` statement):

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(-your-connection-string-here-))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[xyz].[stored_proc]", conn))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    conn.Open();

    // execute your UPDATE statement with an OUTPUT clause into a SqlDataReader
    using(SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        // read the values returned from the OUTPUT clause
        while(reader.Read())
        {
            int insertedID = reader.GetInt32(0);
            // do something with those values....                
        }
    }

    conn.Close();
}
```

This is assuming your UPDATE statement inside your stored procedure would look something like this:

```
UPDATE ...
OUTPUT Inserted.ID    -- or something else....
SET input1 = @input1
WHERE input2 = @input2 
  AND input3 NOT IN (123)
```

Comment: I previously used OUTPUT clause, but this will return something only if an update is performend, null value otherwise. I would always get a defined value, even when update isn't performed.

Comment: @marianoc84: if you're **not updating** anything - what exactly do you want to return then?!?!?! All rows in the table???

Comment: 0 (zero). Anyway i've resolved with your solution. nothing is returned if update isn't happened, in this way while body is never executed and the insertedID (declared outside in my case) is still set to 0. 
If update happens reader.GetInt32(0) set insertedID to 1.